# SSRS: Compare 2 datasets using LookUp

Tags: reporting-services

I have 2 databases and I need to compare the date from one of them with the date from the other one
I know I have to use LookUp but I don't know how to do this 'greater than' between databases.

More or less something like this:

SELECT * FROM database1.table WHERE GetDate(database1.table.date) = GetDate(database2.table.date)

My expression is like this:

```
=LookUp(Format(CDate(Fields!lc_HInicio.Value), "dd-MM-yyyy"), Format(CDate(Fields!dtJornada.Value), "dd-MM-yyyy"), Fields!dtJornada.Value, "DataSet")
```

But some error appears.

thanks

Comment: Edit your question to specify the structure of both datasets.

Comment: Do you need to retrieve the dates from dataset2 which are greater than dates in dataset1?

Comment: Yes, that's  what I need.

Comment: You can do that by creating a custom VB function. However there are some restrictions, the returned dates from the custom code cannot be used as dataset rows. If you specify better your expected result I'd post an answer.